# Jekyllでのカスタム投稿タイプ？の追加

Tags: ruby, jekyll

#### 前提・実現したいこと

静的サイトジェネレーターのJekyllで、_post以外の投稿の追加。

現在wordpressからJekyllへのサイト移行を考えています。

その中で、ブログ以外にも、ニュースとして記事を管理できればと思いました。

Jekyllは_postsにマークダウンで記事を追加し、それをbuildで構築するという形になっていますが、たとえば_newsというフォルダを作りそれも管理することは可能でしょうか？
wordpressでいうカスタム投稿タイプのようなイメージです。

可能であれば設定のご教授をお願いいたします

#### 補足情報(言語/FW/ツール等のバージョンなど)

jekyll 3.2.1

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/44833 マルチポスト

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jekyllが予め決めていないようなディレクトリやファイルはbuildすると普通に`_site`にビルドされます（マークダウンでも書けます。おそらくFront Matterを用意しておけばマークダウンをHTMLに変換してビルドしてくれます）。

今回の要望では `_news`というフォルダではなく`news`というフォルダを自分で作ってそこに必要なファイルを置いてbuildし `ベースURL/news/各ファイル名`というようなアドレスにブラウザでアクセスすればよいように思います。

Comment: なるほど。たしかにそのようにすれば大丈夫そうですね！ありがとうございます！

Comment: @RyoKawamata 解決した場合は回答にチェックをいれてください。チェックがないと未解決として残ってしまいます。またチェックをいれると質問者の信頼度も高まります。